# Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method apply

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to declare a function which accepts 3 parameters and returns an custom object in return like this

```
public static returnResult leadRatingFunction(LeadMaster lead,JSONObject json,String str)
{

}
// Where returnResult and LeadMaster are custom objects
```

I have declared this function in functional interface as follows,

```
@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
@FunctionalInterface

interface Function<LeadMaster,JSONObject,String,returnResult>
{
    public returnResult apply(LeadMaster lead,JSONObject jsonObject,String str);
}
```

I want to use this function as hash map value like this,

```
 Map<String, Function<LeadMaster,JSONObject,String,returnResult>> commands = new HashMap<>();
         commands.put("leadRating",res -> leadRatingFunction(input1 ,input2 ,input3) ) ;
```

But it is giving error as "Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method apply(LeadMaster, JSONObject, String)"

Thank you

Comment: What is `input1 ,input2 ,input3` ? probably not respectivly a `LeadMaster, JSONObject, String` .. EDIT : wait, what are you trying to do with that map exactly ?

Comment: I tried using LeadMaster, JSONObject, String . but it wont work

Comment: Just edit, what do you want to do with the Map ? You need to defined a function like `(lead, json, str) -> ... ` since this is what you declare. You probably should take a look to how to use a lambda and how to declare a function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A lambda expression that matches `Function<LeadMaster,JSONObject,String,returnResult>`, would require three arguments:

```
Map<String, Function<LeadMaster,JSONObject,String,returnResult>> commands = new HashMap<>();
commands.put("leadRating",(a,b,c) -> leadRatingFunction(a,b,c));
```

Alternately, as Lino commented, you can use a method reference:

```
commands.put("leadRating",YourClass::leadRatingFunction);
```

BTW, I'm not sure you want your `Function<LeadMaster,JSONObject,String,returnResult>` interface to be generic, since you placed names of actual classes as generic type parameters.

If you want generic parameters, use generic names:

```
interface Function<A,B,C,D>
{
    public D apply(A a ,B b , C c);
}
```

Otherwise, it doesn't have to be generic:

```
interface Function
{
    public returnResult apply(LeadMaster lead,JSONObject jsonObject,String str);
}
```

Comment: or just `SomeClass::leadRatingFunction`